# cannot get PHP errors to display

Tags: php, error-handling

For some inexplicable reason my PHP wont display errors. I have been writing a script that I am now testing and debugging but all I get is a white page even when I stick an echo 1; on line 1. At the top of my document I have the following error overrides to try and get errors to display:

```
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
ini_set("track_errors", 1);
ini_set("html_errors", 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

I can't change the global `php.ini` file as this would override the settings for other live sites.

Comment: If it is a hosting company, there are many methods like `suhosin` to display the errors. Connect with them, so that they can guide you better.

Comment: it is an unmanaged vps, I have ssh access and I believe suhosin is installed. I don't know how to get this to display errors for me though...

Comment: You have shell access and couldn't change PHP.ini?

Comment: What PHP version? - I've had trouble before with older versions not reporting Parse Errors correctly. Recently I deployed a script with the `const` keyword in it to a machine that was still running 5.1. Full error reporting turned on did __not__ help, nothing in the logs, nada.

Comment: php version 5.3.13. I didn't say I physically couldnt change the php.ini I said I couldnt change it without it affecting other live sites on the server. I can't have errors popping up everywhere on other sites while I debug this script when I should just be able to turn on error displaying for this one process....

Comment: White page with simply `<?php echo '1';` sounds like your error is deeper rooted than just "errors will not display". Are you auto-prepending a file? Any .htaccess changing PHP settings, rewrite rules taking you somewhere unexpected?

Comment: you can set php.ini values in a htaccess file. that might solve your "can't change php.ini" issue, and also might be a place to look for causes for the problems.

Comment: I said I put an echo 1; at the top of the script and get nothing, obviously if I have a php script of just <?php echo 1; ?> then it displays a 1. Effectively there iz a runtime error due to probably a syntax issue somwhere but without erros I can't get PHP to tell me where it is to fix it

Comment: SDC - the server is running cpanel so htaccess error rewrites aren't allowed. Massive pain as this is the way I would usually do it yeah.

Comment: What will be the output of `ini_get("display_errors");` after your ini_set functions? Could be you have no permissions for changing ini configuration through the php file.

Comment: it wouldn't be an error rewrite; it would just be an ini setting.

Comment: even without php displaying the error, you should still be able to get the error message out of the server logs. Also, have you tried running the same php file on your local machine? if there's a syntax error, you should be able to pick it up without having to run it on the server.

Comment: SDC - yeah I know how to do it, my point stands though

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to include failing script in another php file like:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
include('script_that_fails.php');
```

---

EDIT

Short explanation:

If main script contains for example syntax error and environment has error reporting turned off, then even if in main script we'll enable error reporting then it won't success as script won't be executed (because of syntax error). Small trick described above allows to enable error reporting and see the error.

Comment: who the hell just downvoted this, the guy is a genius. the script itself doesnt get chance to reset the php values to display errors because of a runtime error, including it in a separate file as above allows it to sort the display errors then hit the runtime issue. Genius mate well done

Comment: standard, guy puts the right answer up. gets insta down voted

Comment: Guys, I'm too sorry, I firstly got the answer wrong. Just edit your answer to let me vote again.

Comment: Just had the same prob and lupatus reply helped me to resolve it. Another user explained: "...For parsing errors it's too late to enable error_reporting in the invalid script itself, since not even the first line will be run. PHP will abort before seeing the ini_set() or error_reporting(). PHP doesn't interpret scripts line-wise. ..." which made it more clear to me than lupatus words. :)

Answer (score 1):

#### Try this

```
set_error_handler("var_dump");
```

> This function can be used for defining your own way of handling errors during runtime, for example in applications in which you need to do cleanup of data/files when a critical error happens, or when you need to trigger an error under certain conditions (using `trigger_error()`).

Comment: I tried that too and still got a blank screen. It looks like it is a fatal runtime error but I can't go picking through my code looking for a tiny syntax error.

Comment: Do you have access to Apache Logs?