# PHP script won't display errors, just a blank page

Tags: php, error-handling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get useful error messages in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php)

Simple errors in my scripts don't show on the screen, only in `error.log`. I can't find a way to display them on screen. What else can be done here?

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
  knaller!
?>
```

Using PHP Version 5.3.14-1~dotdeb.0

Comment: For parsing errors it's too late to enable error_reporting in the invalid script itself, since not even the first line will be run. PHP will abort before seeing the ini_set() or error_reporting(). PHP doesn't interpret scripts line-wise.

Comment: in httpd.conf set `error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT` and `display_errors = On`

Comment: `Note`: Don't forget to restart apache service ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I had used Search before but did not find the right answer, now it showed up as "Related"...

Here's the story:

- Glavic, none of these suggestions changed anything.
- the related article "[cannot get PHP errors to display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13762089/cannot-get-php-errors-to-display?rq=1)" had the solution to include the file in doubt in another file where error_reporting was set. And with marios comment I also understood why this helped.

That was quick - thanks guys! :)